# Mysql where clause column IN query not giving correct results

Tags: mysql, where-clause, where-in

**Table:**

[image]

From the above table, below query is not giving proper result.

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` 
WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND `columnValue` IN ('50','150');
```

**Result:**

[image]

I need a query for checking the data is changed or not for the perticular packageName and columnValue?

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: it looks correct as per the query, what do you need exactly?

Comment: Like without wildcards is useless. Replace with =

Comment: It should be one record only with columnValue 50 and there is no matching record with columnValue 150.

Comment: The results are valid for given query. You get what you requested.

Comment: @VoolapatiManohar - but there are two rows with `Platinum` and `50`. So the query gives the correct result. You only want to see if there is a row for `50` or `150`?

Comment: I want to check whether these two values are there or not in the columnValue?

Comment: 'I need a query for checking the data is changed or not for the perticular packageName and columnValue?' over what period - the entire period for which you have data or only over the 2 most recent entries or something else?

Comment: you are confused. What is your desired output?

Comment: columnValues == (50,150) ? same or not with active records i.e 2 most recent entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the internal representation of IN

```
Where `columnValue` In (50)     => Where (columnValue = 50)
Where `columnValue` In (50,100) => Where ( (columnValue = 50) OR (columnValue =100) )
```

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` 
WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND `columnValue` IN ('50','150');
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` 
WHERE 
(
    (`packageName` LIKE 'Platinum')
    AND
    (
        (`columnValue` = '50')
        OR (`columnValue` = '100')
    )
);
```

Which will return all Platinum with columnValue 50 or 100.

if you wish to return only platinum 50 or platinum 100, you can group them. (make sure which of the latest record you want by sorting the records)

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` 
WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND `columnValue` IN ('50','150')
GROUP BY `packageName`, `columnValue` ;
```

if you wish to know whether the package values have changed

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile`, Count(distinct `columnValue`) as valueChanges
WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND `columnValue` IN ('50','150')
GROUP BY `packageName` ;
```

you get

```
silver 2
gold 1
platinum 1
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `support_profile`, Count(distinct `columnValue`) as valueChanges should be SELECT *,Count(distinct `columnValue`) as valueChanges
FROM `support_profile`

Comment: Thank you all .    SELECT Count(distinct `columnValue`) as valueChanges FROM `support_profile` WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND `columnValue` IN ('50','150'); By this query i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get records which are IN (50,150) and don't want to compare package name then remove the like condition. Use query as below. I hope this help you to get exact output, and please post your expected output:

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` WHERE `columnValue` IN ('50','150');
```

If You want to check the data which are not match with 50 and 150 then you can try below query:

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND  `columnValue` NOT IN ('50','150');
```

To check if both the data exist in table or not, use AND in WHERE as below:

```
SELECT * FROM `support_profile` WHERE `packageName` LIKE 'Platinum' AND  `columnValue` = '50' AND `columnValue` = '150' ;
```

Comment: I need only not matched records in WHERE `columnValue` IN ('50','150');

Comment: Sorry I m confused,It means you want record which **not** match with 50 and 150?

Comment: Yes.I need a query for checking the data is changed or not for the perticular packageName and columnValue?

Comment: Okay please check edited answer. Hope I understand your qouestion correctly :)

Comment: No. I mean to say that I have an input of (50,150).In the table I have cloumnValue as (50,50). So i wanted to compare these input data. whether the data is same or not.

Comment: Okay you can use AND in WHERE condition. I edited answer, please check.